# The application server IntegratedWebLogicServer does not have the Service Bus runtime installed

Tags: oracle, soa, osb

I have OSB project with JDeveloper 12C, and then I want to deploy the project to my webLogic server.

But getting error:

```
The application server IntegratedWebLogicServer does not have the Service Bus runtime installed
com.bea:Name=Session.ServiceBus,Type=com.bea.wli.config.mbeans.SessionMBean.
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot deploy it on any simple Weblogic server instance. You need to create a [domain that includes the ServiceBus runtime](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/INOSB/toc.htm).

If you used the quickstart installer for JDeveloper/SOA Suite 12c, during development, you can also right-click on your project and "Run" so it should automatically [create an integrated domain](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/core/SOAQS/SOA-INTEGRATING.htm#SOAQS481) for you.